# How to get country from (intl-tel-input) jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

how can I get the name of the selected country from intlTelInput? I have a form with an input hidden this would get the name of the country as selected. but I don't know how to do this

inttelephoneinput.js

```
$(function() {
    $("#mobile-number").intlTelInput({
        preferredCountries: ["us", "co"],
    });
});
```

template
I clarify that the selection of countries and enter number works

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 mg-t-20 mg-md-t-0">
         <input type="code" id="country" vale=" ">
         <label class="form-control-label">Telephone: <span class="tx-danger">*</span></label> <input class="form-control" type="tel" id="mobile-number" name='phone_number' placeholder="e.g. +1 702 123 4567">  
</div>


{% block extra_js %}
<script src="{% static 'template/assets/plugins/telephoneinput/telephoneinput.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'template/assets/plugins/telephoneinput/inttelephoneinput.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

telephoneinput.js
https://jsfiddle.net/4Ljdw6ek/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="tel" id="phone">
<input id="getCountry" type="button" value="Get Country Name"/>
```

and the script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.18/js/intlTelInput-jquery.js" integrity="sha512-OQ4jHPKEPwkASoFbbeWOpNBRSvbwxD5/zSVFWKrRs7BtMve5XbKRWcf2E1Lpfbp9QBnIyVC9DQGwuHczqSokaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

$(function() 
{
    var instance = $("#phone").intlTelInput({
        preferredCountries: ["us", "co"],
    });
    
    $('#getCountry').on('click', function()
    {
      var cdata = instance.intlTelInput('getSelectedCountryData').name;
      alert(cdata);
    });
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o740vfpt/)

Comment: thanks for the quick response but it has not worked, since when entering your code the selector is removed.
normally code: https://ibb.co/VVGcKsQ
with your code: https://ibb.co/FW5qvZZ

Comment: check out this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n52y6ouv/)

Comment: in simple javascript it is functional but in jquery no, I have also tried to insert the script in my template but it does not work

Comment: here you can see the complete code of the plugin telephoneinput.js: https://jsfiddle.net/4Ljdw6ek/